# How should one pass a row index to an applied function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

When using `.apply` in pandas, Is it possible to pass to a function that handles exceptions the row index that is being iterated over, so that the function can inform the user of the row where the unexpected data is located?

```
import os

def split(filename):
    try:
        return os.path.splitext(filename)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error ({e})')
        # Would be nice to know the row index of df

# Make it 'jpg' rather than '.jpg'
df['File Extension'] = df['File Name'].apply(lambda x: split(x)[1][1:])
```

Comment: `df['File Extension'] = df['File Name'].str.extract(r'.([a-z]+)$')` should work if you want to extract file extensions.

Comment: With `Series.apply`, no you cant because `apply` passes the values so there is no index. On the other hand if you use `DataFrame.apply` then you pass a Series to the function and the `Series.name` will be the index of the DataFrame.

Comment: Alternatively, return something like `np.NaN` in the except and subset the DataFrame after you apply the function to check which rows had an issue.

Comment: I've seen a pattern used in Tkinter which allows passing arguments to button commands while iterating, something like this: ```for item in lists:
            m.add_command(label=item, command=lambda v=item: self.epidemic_choice.set(v))``` Can't this be done here?